# ServiceStack "Customizable Fields"

Tags: servicestack

We've been using SS Customizable Fields ("fields=" on the query string) and I think we may be missing a configuration somewhere.  For us, it seems that the field names are case-sensitive - if they don't match the DTO, they're not returned.  However, this is not true for the example that's linked from the AutoQuery GitHub page (changing the casing still results in the correct fields coming back):

[github.servicestack.net/repos.json?fields=Name,Homepage,Language,Updated_At](http://github.servicestack.net/repos.json?fields=Name,Homepage,Language,Updated_At)

What are we missing?

Thanks!

Here's a sample that exhibits the behavior we're seeing:

AppHost:

```
using System.Configuration;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Data;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using ServiceStack.Text;

namespace TestSS.Service {
    public class AppHost : AppHostBase {
        public AppHost()
            : base("TestSS Service", typeof(AppHost).Assembly) {
        }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container) {
            Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryFeature { EnableUntypedQueries = false });
            Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature());

            PreRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes) => {
                if (httpReq.Verb == "OPTIONS")
                    httpRes.EndRequest();
            });

            container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
                new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestSS"].ConnectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));

            JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601;
            JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;
            JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;
        }
    }
}
```

DTOs:

```
using ServiceStack.DataAnnotations;

namespace TestSS.DTO {
    public class Employee {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [References(typeof(Department))]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

        [Ignore]
        public Department Department { get; set; }
    }


    public class Department {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Service:

```
using ServiceStack;
using TestSS.DTO;

namespace TestSS.Service.Services {
    [Route("/employees/{Id}", "GET")]
    public class SingleEmployeeRequest : QueryBase<Employee> {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    [Route("/employees", "GET")]
    public class FindEmployeesRequest : QueryBase<Employee>, IJoin<Employee, Department> {
    }
}
```

Try the following routes:

```
/employees?fields=FirstName,LastName  <-- works

/employees?fields=firstname,LastName  <-- Only LastName returned

/employees?fields=firstname,lastname  <-- All properties returned ?
```

Now, remove the **IJoin** from the FindEmployeesRequest in the Employee service and try the routes again.

```
/employees?fields=FirstName,LastName  <-- works

/employees?fields=firstname,LastName  <-- works

/employees?fields=firstname,lastname  <-- works
```

UPDATE:

The casing issue is fixed with 4.0.55 but there seems to be one more odd behavior with this route:

```
/employees?fields=departmentid
```

The response contains both the DepartmentId **AND** Id properties and the ID values are actually the **DepartmentId** values.  The same is true for this route:

```
/employees?fields=id,departmentid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for case-insensitive custom fields was added [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/234fa52c729b421662a6191a622df030b362142f) with [tests for AutoQuery in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/b302bac9b382d1b6813d579469c2de334a265886). This change is available from v4.0.55 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

You can either use case-sensitive custom fields now, but if you choose to upgrade to the latest version there are some breaking naming changes with AutoQuery that will be later documented in the next v4.0.56 release notes.

Due to a new non-RDBMS version of AutoQuery for supporting custom data sources (called AutoQueryData) we've had to rename some existing AutoQuery attributes so they maintain a consistent isolated nomenclature between the 2 implementations.

The naming changes are captured in the [obsoleted attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/d47916b4372961b87c5e686ce65328d33bd95134/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/IQuery.cs#L122-L139), essentially it involves adding a `Db` suffix to any `[Query]` attributes or `QueryBase<T>` class you're using, i.e:

```
[Obsolete("Use [QueryDb]")]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class QueryAttribute : AttributeBase { }

[Obsolete("Use [QueryDbField]")]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class QueryFieldAttribute : AttributeBase { }

[Obsolete("Use QueryDb")]
public abstract class QueryBase<T> : QueryBase, IQueryDb<T>, IReturn<QueryResponse<T>> { }

[Obsolete("Use QueryDb")]
public abstract class QueryBase<From, Into> 
    : QueryBase, IQueryDb<From, Into>, IReturn<QueryResponse<Into>> { }

[Obsolete("Use IQueryDb<From>")]
public interface IQuery<From> : IQueryDb { }
[Obsolete("Use IQueryDb<From,Into>")]
public interface IQuery<From, Into> : IQueryDb { }
```

Whilst using the existing `QueryBase` class is still supported, it's now obsolete where you should switch to the new `QueryDb` base class at your own leisure.

So instead of:

```
[Route("/movies")]
public class FindMovies : QueryBase<Movie>
{
    public string[] Ratings { get; set; }
}
```

The new base class to use is `QueryDb`, e.g:

```
[Route("/movies")]
public class FindMovies : QueryDb<Movie>
{
    public string[] Ratings { get; set; }
}
```

---

The Release Notes [explains the Custom Fields behavior](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2016/release-notes.md#customizable-fields):

> The Fields still need to be defined on the Response DTO as this feature doesn't change the Response DTO Schema, only which fields are populated. This does change the underlying RDBMS SELECT that's executed, also benefiting from reduced bandwidth between your RDBMS and App Server.
>
> A useful JSON customization that you can add when specifying custom fields is ExcludeDefaultValues, e.g:

```
/query?Fields=Id,Name,Description,JoinTableId&jsconfig=ExcludeDefaultValues
```

Which will remove any value type fields with a default value from the JSON response, e.g:

- http://github.servicestack.net/repos.json?fields=Name,Homepage,Language,Updated_At
- http://github.servicestack.net/repos.json?fields=Name,Homepage,Language,Updated_At&jsconfig=ExcludeDefaultValues

Essentially only the fields you Select are queried and populated on the Response DTO, all other fields have their default values which for reference types is `null` but for ValueTypes, for ints are `0` for DateTime is `DateTime.MinValue`, etc.

The `?jsconfig=ExcludeDefaultValues` modifier instructs ServiceStack's JSON Serializer to omit properties with default values from being serialized, so the link above will instead return:

```
{
    Total: 30,
    Results: [
    {
        Name: "ServiceStack",
        Homepage: "https://servicestack.net",
        Language: "C#",
        Updated_At: "/Date(1443370980000+0000)/"
    },
    {
        Name: "ServiceStack.Examples",
        Homepage: "https://servicestack.net",
        Language: "C#",
        Updated_At: "/Date(1443326228000+0000)/"
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Read the release notes completely and love the "jsconfig=ExcludeDefaultValues"  BUT my issue is the casing of the field names.  In your service above, I can change "fields=Name..." to "fields=name..." or "fields=NAME..." and the Name property is always returned in the response.  But for my service, that doesn't work - if the casing doesn't match, the property is not returned in the response.

Comment: @user3146832 You haven't provided any info about your Service. i.e. What RDBMS are you using? What is the POCO class are you seeing this on? What's your AutoQuery Request DTO look like? Are you using a Custom Request AutoQuery Service? Are you using any custom JsConfig configuration? etc. It's impossible to repro or identify your issue without having anything to go on.

Comment: I'll do some more research.  I have a service here at home that behaves as it should - it is case **insensitive**.  I'm not sure what's going on with the service at work.  Thanks, you've given me places to look.

Comment: We've narrowed it down to IJoin.  I've edited the question and added some sample code.  We are using SQL Server (2008 and 2012).  Let me know what you think.  Thanks.

Comment: @user3146832 An updated version of ServiceStack with support for case-insensitive custom fields is [now available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet), although please be aware of the AutoQuery naming changes before upgrading.

Comment: Thanks for the quick (as usual) response!  The case-sensitive issue is resolved but we're seeing one more odd behavior - see UPDATE above.

Comment: @user3146832 Should now be resolved with latest v4.0.55 on MyGet, you'll need to [clear your NuGet cache](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet#redownloading-myget-packages) to pull down the latest v4.0.55 packages.